# Adjacent Sibling & General Sibling Selectors not selecting properly

Tags: html, css

I tried to use Adjacent Sibling Selector and General Sibling Selector to color the paragraphs coming after the anchor tag. First element (stories) is not being styled when I use the selector. All the preceding elements are styled properly. I would like to know why is this happening?

html code is as follows:

```
<a class="mylink" href="stories.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80" /></a>
<p>Stories</p>

<a class="mylink" href="movies.html" target="_blank" style="color : blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80" /></a>
<p>Movies</p>

<a class="mylink" href="tables.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80" /></a>
<p>Tables</p>

<a class="mylink" href="login.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80" /></a>
<p>Login Page</p>
```

Adjacent Sibling Selector:

```
a + p {
  color: green;
}
```

General Sibling Selector:

```
a ~ p {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: This should work. Please demonstrate it NOT working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This may be an issue of specificity. The selector is working, see snippet below. Your style might be getting overridden by another style you have defined. On your browser inspector, inspect the `<p>` element and if you see `color: green;` with a strikethrough, then that means it has been overridden. Some browser inspectors will even tell you which other rule is overriding it. In any case, try adding [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) if you truly can't find the specificity issue.

```css
a + p {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="mylink" href="stories.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80"/></a><p>Stories</p>

<a class="mylink" href="movies.html" target="_blank" style="color : blue" ><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80" /></a><p>Movies</p>

<a class="mylink" href="tables.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80"/></a><p>Tables</p>

<a class="mylink" href="login.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue"><img src="abc.png" alt="Image Not Available" height="80"/></a> <p>Login Page</p>
```

Comment: Yeah . It was being overridden . But I am not sure why all the other elements were not having this issue but the first one. I tried to change the order but it remained the same.